# ActiveX component can't create object: 'MSXML2.DOMDocument'

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, 64-bit, activex

I am trying to create an instance of the object Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0, but I am getting the following error:
**ActiveX component can't create object: 'MSXML2.DOMDocument'**

The error occures in this line:
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0")

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably the specific version 4.0 of Msxml2.DOMDocument is not (properly) installed on the computer your script runs on. Try to create the version-independent object:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
```

This should give you the version that 'works' on your machine. If this fails, try

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
```

or experiment with the version number. Use `TypeName(xmlDoc)` to get a hint wrt the effective version.

P.S. If your problem is caused by 32 vs. 64 bit troubles, [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/install-msxml4-in-windows-7-to-run-classic-asp/a268f889-df55-42e9-bd0f-c4623ed5a6f4) may give you further hints for things to check.

Answer (score 6):

Check if `msxml4.dll` exists on your system. and (re-)register the library if it does:

```
cd %SystemRoot%\system32
regsvr32 /u msxml4.dll
regsvr32 msxml4.dll
```

You need admin privileges to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Three things you need to check:

1. While registering MSXML4 make sure the MSXML4r.dll is at the same path as MSXML4.dll
2. Register using proper syntax
   Regsvr32 msxml4.dll
3. Enable 32 bit in IIS app pool

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34517442)